# Merge two dictionaries in python with lists as values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries with lists as their values.
I want to merge them preserving unique item in the lists.
What I know is:

```
d1 = {'a':['aa','bb']}
d2 = {'a':['aa','cc'],'b':['xx','yy']}
d1.update(d2)
print d1
>>> {'a': ['aa', 'cc'], 'b': ['xx', 'yy']}
```

While I want to get

```
>>> {'a': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'], 'b': ['xx', 'yy']}
```

What is the most efficient way of achieving this?

Comment: So, in essence, your values should be *sets*, not lists, since you are only retaining unique elements.

Comment: Padraic Cunningham no it doesn't

Comment: @user3399516, then sets are the way to go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use sets instead of lists:

```
{k: set(d1.get(k, [])) | set(d2.get(k, [])) for k in d1.viewkeys() | d2}
```

For your sample input this produces:

```
>>> d1 = {'a':['aa','bb']}
>>> d2 = {'a':['aa','cc'],'b':['xx','yy']}
>>> {k: set(d1.get(k, [])) | set(d2.get(k, [])) for k in d1.viewkeys() | d2}
{'a': set(['aa', 'cc', 'bb']), 'b': set(['yy', 'xx'])}
```

This would be easier if you changed your input dictionaries to use sets for the values too.

If you must have lists and order doesn't matter, convert the sets back to lists:

```
{k: list(set(d1.get(k, [])) | set(d2.get(k, []))) for k in d1.viewkeys() | d2}
```

Comment: Is there any point in calling `.viewkeys()` on the second dict?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: there isn't; removed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you. If I do use sets for input dictionaries such as d1 = {'a':set(['aa','bb'])}, how would it work then?

Comment: @user3399516: `{k: d1.get(k, set()) | d2.get(k, set()) for k in d1.viewkeys() | d2}`